# jshint ignore comments everywhere

Tags: jshint

How can I get jshint to ignore all comments?

For example, in my code I have:

```
// this is a very long line this is a very long line this is a very long line this is
var x = 2;
```

This gives an error because the comment is too long. I want jshint to ignore comments everywhere throughout my app. Is this possible?